# Hockey-Stick Theorem for Multinomial Coefficients

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, multinomial-coefficients

Pascal's triangle has this famous [hockey stick identity](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Combinatorial_identity). 
$$ \binom{n+k+1}{k}=\sum_{j=0}^k \binom{n+j}{j}$$
Wonder what would be the form for [multinomial coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\binom{a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_t}{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_t}=\sum_{i=2}^t \sum_{j=1}^{i-1} \sum_{k=1}^{a_i} \binom{ a_1+a_2+\cdots+a_{i-1}+k }{a_1,a_2,\cdots,a_j-1,\cdots,a_{i-1},k }$$